# Simplifying an equation from $a - b(c)$ to $a(b) - b(c)$.

Tags: polynomials

A section in a book shows jumping from

$$7-3(9-7) = 1$$

to

$$4(7)-3(9) = 1$$

I can't see how this happens. What steps have been taken?
Where did the four come from?

Comment: $-3(-7) + 7 = 4(7)$

Comment: Your title is misleading. Rather, you are simplifying from the form $a-b(c-a)$ to the form $d(a)-b(c).$ In particular, $d=b+1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$7-3(9-7) = 1$

$7-3(9)-3(-7)=1$ Via the distributive property.

$7+3(7)-3(9)=1$ By moving terms around and simplifying the product of two negatives.

$7(1+3)-3(9)=1$ By factoring out $7$ from the first two terms.

$4(7)-3(9)=1=7-3(9-7)$ And we are finished.

Answer (score 0):

The equation that you have is equivalent to:

$$7 + 3(7) - 3(9) = 1$$

And this is equal to the expression you're asking about

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows to see the final result:
\begin{align}
& 7-3(9-7) \\
= & 1(7)-3(9)+3(7) \\
= & 4(7) -3(9)\\
=&1
\end{align}